# Ninject Singleton Scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scope, ninject

I was wondering what situations a Ninject Singleton scope could be useful in ASP.NET MVC.  I was thinking in situations when the dependency didn't have any properties/variables that could change. For example a mapper class that just takes in an object or two and maps it to a new object.

```
public class AccountMapper : IAccountMapper
{
  public IList<WebAccount> Map(Account[] accounts)
  {
    if (accounts == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("accounts");

    Account acct;
    List<WebAccount> authorizedAccounts = new List<WebAccount>();
    foreach (var account in accounts)
    {
        if (account.active == 0)
        {
            acct = new WebAccount     (                                                        
                                                account.active == 0 ? true : false,
                                                account.account_number,
                                                account.agreement_no                                                        
                                            );

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acct.AccountNumber))
                acct.AccountNumber = acct.AccountNumber.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(acct.ArgreementNo))
                acct.ArgreementNo = acct.ArgreementNo.Trim();

            authorizedAccounts.Add(acct);

        }
    }
    return authorizedAccounts;
```

}
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use that class in `SingletonScope()` because it doesn't hold any properties or attributes that could be potentially affected by other threads, but you should also be aware that adding instance-data may break your code.

You can read more about Singleton Scope here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes and see other opinions: [When to use Singleton vs Transient vs Request using Ninject and MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348106/when-to-use-singleton-vs-transient-vs-request-using-ninject-and-mongodb)